# Scalar derivative of ${\rm tr}~[A(x)\log A(x)]$ where $A(x)$ is a square matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, entropy, statistical-mechanics

How do i proceed to calculate

$$\frac{d}{dx}{\rm tr}\left[{A(x) \log A(x)}\right]$$

where $A(x) \in \mathbb{M}(n)$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

The $\log$ function is the one defined by the exponential map for matrices in the following sense: If $A=e^B$ then $B=\log A$, where $e ^X \equiv \sum_{k=0}^\infty X^k / k! $. The multiplication between $A$ and $\log A$ is matrix multiplication.

Further assume that $A(x)$ are diagonalizable and nonsingular.

This problem arises in a statistical physics model where $A(x)$ is a density matrix depending on a scalar quantity and the trace expression is the (von Neumann) entropy. I tried to find it on the net but no luck and i got confused with the literature on matrix derivatives that are usually for derivation with respect to another matrix or with respect to a vector. Thanks anyone!

Comment: What is the log of a rectangular matrix? Is it the entrywise log?

Comment: Same for multiplication $A(x)\log A(x)$, is it entrywise ? I suspect so since you say matrices are rectangular. Anyway, this just sums up to a standard derivative after the trace.

Comment: Your log is not well defined then

Comment: why do you say that?

Comment: 1/ $X\rightarrow \exp X$ is well defined because this is a power serie with infinite radius of convergence, but as you might know, the inverse is not defined trivially (e.g. $\exp$ maps matrices into the invertibles ones). 2/ If your matrices aren't square, then $X^k$ in the exponential doesn't mean anything

Comment: 1/ i don't see your point here (maybe i missed it), i never mentioned anything about an inverse, i gave the definition of the log map with respect to the exponential map. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix 2/ you are right about this, it was a typo i meant square matrix, i corrected it..

Comment: About 1/ How do you compute $\log A$ ? You defined a function wrt an equation, and without further details this is not well defined. It's the same as saying : "consider $x$ such that $|x| = 1$". There is more than one such $x$ (e.g. $\{e^{i\theta},\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$), and in fact for a logartihm on matrices,  your equation has infinitely many solutions, at least the way you write this. I suspect some details are missing to define the correct $\log$

Comment: well i am not sure.. The formula i give is the Von Neumann entropy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy , the log is the one given there.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, this is the log for symmetric matrices, so you can define any operator on the eigenvalues. Now you need to give an explicit $A(x)$ because as far as I know there is no way to derive a closed form expression for your entropy in the most general case. Especially since we are talking about eigenvalues, derivation of these wrt to a parameter in general is a complicated problem.

Comment: thank you for the comments, learned a couple of things from these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just carry out the chain rule as you would normally.
$$ \frac{d}{dx}{\rm tr}\left[{A(x) \log A(x)}\right] = {\rm tr} [A'(x)\log A(x) + A(x)A^{-1}(x)A'(x)]$$
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form).

Comment: Well this i like a lot since it is simple! So, i can just move the differential operation inside the trace then, $d(trX)=tr(dX) $? How about Bertrand R's previous comment/objection?

Comment: I don't understand why Bertrand R is getting all caught up in the technical details. Any diagonalizable square nonsingular matrix has a well defined principal log.

Comment: ok well thanks a lot to everyone; for the moment i am voting this up and unless it turns out not to be correct i am very happy with it!

Comment: Hmm, deriving the trace is indeed quite simple but I don't think deriving the log is that easy. My first guess would be that $\frac{d \;}{dx} \log A(x)=A(x)^{-1}A'(x)$ only if $A(x)$ and $A'(x)$ commute and in general it's not the case. So I don't think that works here.

Comment: Because of the trace it works. But in general it is wrong to write $\log(A(x))' = A'(x)\log A(x) + A'(x)$. Anyway, my point was precisely to find out that the matrix was something, in this case diagonalizable and nonsingular. And it's not a "technical detail"

Comment: Oh yeah, with the cyclicity of the trace, that works : my bad.

Comment: Since it was stated that $A$ is a density matrix, it is safe to assume all those things. Furthermore, since in general the derivative exists in physics in these kinds of parameterized entropy situations, it is also reasonable to assume that these simple expressions for the derivative hold, and verify later.

Comment: @Victor Liu , your result is correct but I see no proof. With your reference, you can obtain the derivative of $tr(\log(A))$ but not the derivative of $tr(A\log(A))$ (moreover, if $A$ has complex eigenvalues, then  $\log(\det(A))$ and $tr(\log(A))$ are not necessarily equal).

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $A(x)$ has no eigenvalues in $(-\infty,0]$ and $\log$ denotes the principal logarithm. Since $g(A)=\log(A)$ is a matrix function, (E):  $\log(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$. Let $P$ be a polynomial and $f:x\rightarrow tr(P(A)\log(A))$. According to (E), $f'(x)=tr(P'(A)\log(A)A')+tr(P(A)Dg_A(A'))$.

Now $Dg_A(A')=\int_0^1(t(A-I)+I)^{-1}A'(t(A-I)+I)^{-1}dt$; then $tr(P(A)Dg_A(A'))=\int_0^{1}tr(P(A)(t(A-I)+I)^{-1}A'(t(A-I)+I)^{-1})dt=\int_0^{1}tr(P(A)(t(A-I)+I)^{-2}A')dt=tr(P(A)A'\int_0^1(t(A-I)+I)^{-2}dt)=tr(P(A)A'A^{-1})$.

Finally $f'(x)=tr((P'(A)\log(A)+P(A)A^{-1})A')$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op{\operatorname}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}(#1)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
$Given a scalar function $f(z),\,$ and its derivative
$$\eqalign{
g(z) &= \deriv fz \\
}$$
and a square matrix $(A)$ which is a function of a scalar parameter $(x)$
$$\eqalign{
A' &= \deriv Ax \\
}$$
Apply these functions using $A$ as the argument and take the trace
$$\eqalign{
F &= f(A), \qquad G = g(A), \qquad h = \trace{F} \\
}$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of the trace
$$\eqalign{
dh &= \trace{G\;dA} &= \trace{GA'}\,dx \\
\deriv hx &= \trace{GA'} &= \trace{A'G} \\
}$$
In the current problem
$$\eqalign{
f(z) &= z\:\log(z) &\qiq F = A\:\log(A) \\
g(z) &= {\tt1}+\log(z) &\qiq G = I+\log(A) \\
}$$
therefore
$$\eqalign{
\deriv{}x\trace{A\log(A)} \;=\; \trace{A' + A'\log(A)} \\
}$$