# Proof of a variational trace inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, proof-writing

The property I refer to is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Gibbs_variational_principle). It says that for any positive semidefinite $\gamma$ with $\text{Tr}(\gamma) = 1$ and self-adjoint $H$, the following inequality holds

> $\text{Tr}(\gamma H) - \text{Tr}(\gamma\log\gamma) \leq \log\text{Tr}\exp(H)$ with equality if and only if $\gamma = \frac{\exp(H)}{\text{Tr}(\exp(H))}$

To prove this for positive definite $\gamma$ is easy. The left hand side is concave in $\gamma$ and differentiable. Taking the derivative and setting it to zero gives the desired result.

However, the result is claimed for positive semidefinite matrices and in this case, the term $\text{Tr}(\gamma\log\gamma)$ is not differentiable as answered in the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243283/derivative-of-tr-rho-log-rho).

How does one complete the proof?

Comment: Do you know that the lhs is strictly concave? Then you could use that a critical point of a strictly concave function is necessarily the unique global maximum.

Comment: @Vogel the lhs is concave but I do not know if it is strictly concave. Also, how does one find the critical point in this case? (I only know how to do it by taking the derivative and that doesn't seem valid here)

Comment: If $\gamma$ is positive semi-definite but not positive definite then it has an eigenvalue which is zero and is not invertible. The logarithm of a matrix only exists when the matrix is invertible. So the inequality only applies when $\gamma$ is positive definite. +1 for spotting an error on Wikipedia.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson the logarithm only exists if the matrix is invertible but the quantity $\text{Tr}(\rho\log\rho)$ is well defined, even for positive semidefinite matrices. I think there is no problem there - but the proof technique needs to be subtle precisely because of your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $\gamma$ is Hermitian and hence diagonalisable (most authors only define positive semi-definteness for Hermitian matrices, but some use alternative definitions).

Define $\text{Tr}(\gamma\log\gamma)=\sum \lambda_i\log\lambda_i$ where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\gamma$ (some of these eigenvalues may be repeated) and $0\log 0=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\epsilon\log\epsilon=0$

Diagonalize $\gamma$ as $\gamma=UDU^{-1}$ and define $\gamma_{\epsilon}=U(D+\epsilon I)U^{-1}$. Then $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ is positive definite for all $\epsilon>0$.

We will define $f(\epsilon)=\text{Tr}(\gamma_\epsilon H)-\text{Tr}(\gamma_\epsilon \log \gamma_\epsilon)-\log \text{Tr}\exp( H)$.

If we can prove that $f(\epsilon)$ is left-continuous at zero, 
then $f(\epsilon)\leq 0$ for $\epsilon>0$ implies $f(0)\leq 0$. To prove continuity of the term $\text{Tr}(\gamma_\epsilon \log \gamma_\epsilon)$, note that 
$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} (\lambda_i+\epsilon) \log (\lambda_i+\epsilon)=\lambda_i \log \lambda_i$ .