# Derivative of the von Neumann entropy

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877997/derivative-of-von-neumann-entropy) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333779/scalar-derivative-of-rm-trax-log-ax-where-ax-is-a-square-matrix)

I'm trying to compute the derivative of $S(X) = Tr(X\log(X))$. An additional condition is that $X = L^TL$ for some $L$ and I want to take the derivative with respect to $L$. So essentially, I would like to find $$\frac{\partial Tr\left(L^TL\log(L^TL)\right)}{\partial L}$$ This is well defined as it's the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a matrix so I should obtain a matrix of size $L$.

My progress so far:

Use the product rule to break it up into two derivatives. So I have $\frac{\partial Tr(L^T L C)}{\partial L}$, where $C = \log(L^TL)$ but is treated as a constant. According to the matrix cookbook, I get $L(C^T + C) = L(\log(L^TL))^T + L\log(L^TL)$.

The other term, $\frac{\partial Tr(C'\log(L^T L) )}{\partial L}$, is more troublesome. I thought about letting $L^TL = X$ and use the chain rule, but I'm not sure how to deal with the $\frac{\partial X}{\partial L}$ term since I now have the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix (instead of scalar with matrix).

So the question, after my work, is now how to do take the derivative of the second term. Alternatively, if the product rule was a bad idea and I can do it more directly, that would also be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following scalar function and its derivative.
$$\eqalign{
f(x) &= x\,\log(x) \cr f'(x) &= 1 + \log(x)
}$$
When the function is applied to a matrix argument the result is a matrix
$$F = f(X)$$
The differential of the trace of $F$ is then
$$\eqalign{
d\,{\rm Tr}(F) &= f'(X)^T:dX \cr
 &= \big(I+\log(X)\big)^T:dX \cr
}$$
Now assume that $X$ is described in terms of another matrix $L$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X &= L^TL \cr
dX &= L^T\,dL + dL^T\,L \cr
}$$
Substituting this into the previous result yields
$$\eqalign{
d\,{\rm Tr}(F)
 &= \big(I+\log(L^TL)\big)^T:(L^T\,dL + dL^T\,L) \cr
 &= 2\,\big(I+\log(L^TL)\big):L^T\,dL \cr
 &= 2\,L\big(I+\log(L^TL)\big):dL \cr
\frac{\partial{\,\rm Tr}(F)}{\partial L} &= 2\,\big(L+L\log(L^TL)\big) \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:** In some steps above, a colon is used as a product notation for the trace, i.e. 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Great answer! Just one question: How did you go from $\big(I+\log(L^TL)\big)^T:(L^T\,dL + dL^T\,L)$ to $2\big(I+\log(L^TL)\big):(L^T\,dL)$? Thank you

Comment: It follows from these easily proved statements $$\eqalign{
(L^TdL)^T &= (L^TdL) \cr
(\log(L^TL)+I)^T &= (\log(L^TL)+I) \cr
A^T:B &= A:B^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Oops!  It follows from these easily proved statements (correcting my previous comment) $$\eqalign{ (L^TdL)^T &= (dL^TL) \\ (\log(L^TL)+I)^T &= (\log(L^TL)+I) \\ A^T:B &= A:B^T}$$